# Let centered text overflow on both sides

Tags: jquery, html, animation, overflow, center

I'd like to make an "coming in" animation on a horizontal and vertical centered text. Before the animation runs, the text will be wider than the view port. During the animation, the font-size and the letter-spacing of the text will be reduced, so that the text will fit in the view port after the animation.

The problem is, that the text only overflows the the left and is not centered as long as the text is wider than the view port. [See my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/P3sJe/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="welcome">
    <div id="welcome_text_wrap">
         <div id="welcome_text">sometext</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page_container">
     <h2>Page Content</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#welcome {
     width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: black;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}

#welcome_text_wrap {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
}

#welcome_text {
    font-size: 40vw;
    letter-spacing: 1em;
    font-family: serif;
    color: white;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline;
}

.after_animation {
    font-size: 12vw !important;
    letter-spacing: 0em !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function show_welcome() {
$("#welcome").css("display", "table");

$("#welcome_text").addClass("after_animation", {
    duration: 5000,
    children: true,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuint',
    complete: function() {
        setTimeout(4000, $("#welcome").fadeOut(800));
    }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
     show_welcome();
});
```

How can I center the text, even if it does not fit into the view port? Also, is there a better way to do this kind of animation? Maybe using CSS 3 transitions?

Thanks allot,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped #welcome with #welcome_container with css:

```
#welcome_container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

For #welcome I changed:

```
#welcome {
    ...
    min-width: 4000px;
    max-width: 4000px;
    ...
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-2000px;
    top:0;
}
```

See it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/P3sJe/13/

Answer (score 0):

you must reduce the font-sizeof the welcome_text div!, and use width of 90% with some padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3sJe/12/

**css**

```
#welcome {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 5%;
}
#welcome_text {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```